# copyright symbol in will print &amp;&reg;

Tags: php

I want to use ®( ®) in my php page.
Tried as `$var ='test'.&#174 .'title';` getting site error.How to use it with string in php

HTML Character Entities in php page

```
   $vars['head_title'] = 'test'.htmlentities('&reg;').'string title';
```

in output will get `test&amp;&reg;string title`
How to use reserved symbol in php

Comment: how are you outputting `$vars['head_title']`?

Comment: yes outputting head_title

Comment: but how. ..........

Comment: in drupal template

Comment: `htmlentities('&reg;')` makes no sense. `&reg;` **is** an html entity. Why are you trying to encode at as an html entity? It already is. Just `echo '&reg;'` does what you want.

Comment: What is wrong with just `$vars['head_title'] = 'test ® string title';` …? Drupal should be fully UTF-8 compatible (unless you explicitly made it otherwise), so why would this need _entities_ anywhere in the first place?

Comment: (And FYI, the copyright symbol is `©`. `®` is the _registered trademark_ symbol.)

Comment: Did you try just `$var = 'test&#174title';`? Are you using XML?

Comment: Try this to convert entity **&reg;**    
```$vars['head_title'] = htmlspecialchars_decode('test &reg; string title');```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use `htmlentities` incorrectly, taken from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

> This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.
>
> If you want to decode instead (the reverse) you can use html_entity_decode().

You want the reverse, [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
<?php
    echo 'test '.htmlentities('&reg;').'string title'; # doesn't work
    echo 'test '.html_entity_decode('&reg;').'string title'; # works
```

see [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/BJcRM)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use htmlentities function you can directly print it like:-

```
$vars['head_title'] = "test &reg; string title";
```